# jQuery Ajax validation and DataAnnotations attributes

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a form that posts and gets results through jQuery AJAX. Now I need to put some validation stuff on it. I wonder how to do it. Should I use jQuery validation plugin? If I use it and if I'm guessing right - there is no need to decorate the model with DataAnnotations attributes, they no longer gonna make any sense, right?

So basically that I'm saying: I use a normal html form `Html.BeginForm()`, not an AJAX form, then I override the form's submit() function

```
$("form[action$='UpdateCalendarForm']").submit(function () 
{
    $.ajax({
            url:  $(this).attr("action"),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(calendarData),
            dataType: "json", 
            success: updateCalendarCallback
           });
    return false; // it wouldn't actually rerender the page
});

function updateCalendarCallback(result){
 // And here I just do something on the page
}
```

What's the best way to add some validation here without Ajax helper methods (but using jQuery) and DataAnnotations attributes on the Model properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brad Wilson had great [video on mvcConf](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2011-Brad-Wilson-Advanced-MVC-3) about validation. Here's everything you will need to know to start implementing custom validation on mvc3

Comment: I don't need custom validation functionality (at least yet). I have a property in my model decorated with RequiredAttribute, and it doesn't work, because I'm using jQuery ajax. How to force client validation in this case?

Comment: That was my bad. I missed 
jquery.validate.min.js 
and 
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js